# Session is resetting every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a action where I am adding ebooks when user click on add to chart link. But when I look after adding one ebook in session, there is empty session. How to fix it. I want to maintain all ebooks after adding by user for buying item.

My action is

```
def add_to_chart
  session[:added_to_chart] ||={}
  ebook = Ebook.find params[:id]
  session[:added_to_chart].merge!({params[:id]=>ebook})
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was forgot to add render or redirect_to at last line so it throws error at reseting session

```
def add_to_chart
  session[:added_to_chart] ||={}
  ebook = Ebook.find params[:id]
  session[:added_to_chart].merge!({params[:id]=>ebook})
  render :text=>"success!"
end
```